# How to render ion-checkbox dynamically in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, checkbox, ionic3

I want to render `ion-checkbox` dynamically in my html page. I tried using below:

In .ts file:

```
sanitizeLetterBody = (letterBody): string => {
  let replaceText = "<ion-item><ion-label><b>Read and approved with initials below. </b></ion-label><ion-checkbox class='letter-initials'></ion-checkbox></ion-item>";
  return letterBody.split("#PAT_SIGN_INITIAL#").join(replaceText);
}
```

In .html file:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col class="padding-top-10 padding-left-0 padding-right-0 padding-bottom-0">
        <div class="letter-body white-space-pre-line" [innerHTML]="customLetterData.LetterBody | safeHtml:'html'"></div>
    </ion-col> 
</ion-row>
```

But, the checkbox did not render in the html page like below:

[image]

Then i tried using `<input type='checkbox'>` like below:

```
sanitizeLetterBody = (letterBody): string => {
  let replaceText = "&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='check-pat-initials' name='test'><b>Read and approved with initials below.</b>&nbsp;";
  return letterBody.split("#PAT_SIGN_INITIAL#").join(replaceText);
}
```

The checkbox is rendered nicely but **i can't check or un-check the checkbox**. May be no events are binding in this fashion.

[image]

1. Why can't i check or un-check the checkbox which are rendered dynamically?
2. Is there any different approach to achieve this?

Comment: Checkbox coming dynamic right? based on something like array ?

Comment: A string contains some data like `"#a# Hello #a#"`.. And we will replace this #a# from the string with a checkbox. And then fit this string in div innerHTML. We can check or uncheck this chekboxes

Comment: I am thinking to use like take all string in array which you need to display with checkbox and execute ngFor in html

Comment: Can you show me snippet? I am not understanding you. Did you understand my question?